# Inconsistency broke Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I was attempting to fix an import error from pygattlib to glib, attempting to follow various advice from people online. However, after running the command `conda install -c rmg glibc` I seem to have created a really problematic conflict.
Whenever I use a conda command I get the error    `` Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-call-libc-early-init.c: 37: _dl_call_libc_early_init: Assertion `sym != NULL' failed! ``

Does anyone have any advice? Thank you.

P.S. Its a bit off topic, but if anyone has any idea how to fix the initial error it would be very appreciated:

```
ImportError: /home/hcvarekamp/.anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python39.so.1.74.0)
```

Comment: In such situations it's better to use virtual environment!

Comment: I am using anaconda virtual enviroments (though this was unfortunately done in base admittedly). I can't activate any other environments or anything since this error started. Do you have any advice on a workaround?

Comment: uninstall and reinstall anaconda?  (hence why @Shayan said its better to use a virtual env ... that way thats all you have to delete  and reinstall)

Comment: Im' not familiar with this error but i saw some people mentioned installing `libgcc`. Make sure to google it and read some details.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the same thing. I think I have to start with a clean installation of anaconda but then I may try starting with libgcc

Comment: Just make sure to use virtual environments. It's easy to create and remove. And doesn't make trouble in your base env! Also I recommend to create conda venv using .yml files! This way is great! You can mention all packages you need in .yml file, then anaconda install the version of each that doesn't make inconsistency with others.